# Button preventing further scrolling

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, xcode4.6

i have a scrollview in place, which is working as expected however if i add a reactive button to the scrollview it no longer has scroll functionality.

**Edit:**

I have discovered that the constraints of the button are what is at play preventing scroll of the scrollview. ill need to find a way to programmatically modify the constraints of an arbitrary number of buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Select the button** then `File -> inspector` and disable **'auto-layout'**

This will remove the constraints causing the lock up of scroll in the scrollview